# Django how to preserve request body across redirects?

Tags: django, forms, django-views

I have a view like so:

```py
class ConfirmCancellationView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        #has request.foo - the thing to cancel
        return render(request, "confirm_cancellation.html")
```

The html for this view:

```html
<form method="post" action="{% url 'cancel_entry' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="btn--primary" type="submit" id="cancel">Yes, cancel instruction</button>
</form>
```

The problem is, while my `ConfirmCancellation` has the information I want to cancel (called `foo`in the code ), the SAME request is not passed to my `cancel_entry` view. It complains that `foo` is not an attribute...

How do i make it so that the same request, containing `foo`, is passed to the redirect url?

Comment: what is the `cancel_entry` view? where is the redirect?

Answer (score 0):

You can just use `context` to pass data to your templates:

```py
# your view
class ConfirmCancellationView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        context = {
            "foo": request.foo
        }
        return render(request, "confirm_cancellation.html", context)
```

Comment: cool thanks! Just wondering,  when i redirect to `cancel_entry` will this context be present in the request body?

Comment: Also my concern is the "foo" is a very sensitive variable...I don't quite want it exposed in the code

Comment: You can do that if you pass the same context when rendering `cancel_entry` such as: `render(request, "cancel_entry.html", context)`

Comment: Putting `foo` in your context when rendering an html template is safe. Just do not pass `foo` between views.